# Remaping numbers in table all at once

Tags: mysql

I was converting a database structure to a different one. There's this problem with ID's. The items used to reference to each other with ID - but these ID's *must* change because the new structure is different.

So you have a table (this is *an example*):

```
 | id | ref |
 +----+-----+
 |  1 |   3 |
 |  2 |   1 |
 |  3 |   1 |
 |  4 |   2 |
```

Now let's say that in new table, the `ref`ference id's must change like this:

```
 | old | new |
 +-----+-----+
 |  1  |  2  |
 |  2  |  1  |
 |  3  |  4  |
 |  4  |  3  |
```

See what happens if you subsequently `UPDATE` to replace old `ref` with new ones:

```
Replacing: 1=>2  Replacing: 2=>1     This is what we need at the end:
                   well, damn
 | id | ref |     | id | ref |           | id | ref |
 +----+-----+     +----+-----+           +----+-----+ 
 |  1 |  3  |     |  1 |  3  |           |  1 |  4  |
 |  2 | *2* |     |  2 |  2  |           |  2 |  2  | 
 |  3 | *2* |     |  3 |  2  |           |  2 |  2  | 
 |  4 |  2  |     |  4 | *2* |           |  2 |  1  |
```

So I need to replace it at one time. How can I do this?

Comment: By what criteria do you determine that 1 becomes 2 and 2 becomes one?

Comment: @GolezTrol By criteria that would make this post 3 times longer. It doesn't matter. If you're really interested, here's a [question about my specific database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26002256/607407) case. Nobody has understood it - so good luck.

Comment: You sound like that is my problem, but to me it seems it is yours. I'm not particularly interested in your database, I just requested -what I think is- necessary information for providing a good answer to your question.

Comment: I'm doing my best to make my questions clear. I intentionally omit as much personal stuff as possible to increase chance that the answer will also apply to other user's questions. And whoever posted that close vote was just randomly clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the criteria don't matter, this will do the trick. The core of the solution is: update all rows in one go.

```
update YourTable
set ref = 
    case ref
        when 1 then 2
        when 2 then 1
        when 3 then 4
        when 4 then 3
    end
```

If that is not possible:

- add a new column 'newref'
- update 'newref' in any way you want to contain the new ids
- update the 'ref' column with the values from 'newref'
- drop the 'newref'

Answer (score 0):

This update all in one instruction

```
UPDATE t1 a
INNER JOIN  t2 b
 ON a.ref=b.old
SET a.ref=b.new;
```

Result

```
select * from t1

id  ref
1   4
2   2
3   2
4   1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab49c/1

Schema and data sample

```
create table t1 (id int, ref int);
create table t2 (old int, new int);

insert t1 values(1,3);
insert t1 values(2,1);
insert t1 values(3,1);
insert t1 values(4,2);

insert t2 values(1,2);
insert t2 values(2,1);
insert t2 values(3,4);
insert t2 values(4,3);
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but I didn't have the table with value map, so I used the `case`. But I'm sure it will help somebody else. By the way, you don't have to remind yourself by the spam comments. I'm active member for a few years and I gracefully read the answers I get.